# How to call closures of a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';


class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(){
      // I want to call myClosure
  }

  render() {
    return <Counter/>;
  }
}


function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function myClosure(){
     console.log('Closure called');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the code `Counter` is a functional component and has a `myClosure` closure, How can I call `myClosure` in `MyComponent` ? As functional component has no `ref` and I think `forwardRef` cannot help me!

Comment: That is an anti-pattern. Perhaps your problem can be solved by [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: @JosephD. Yes I know